# Regex for GitHub flavored markdown of repos and issues

Tags: ruby, regex, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to find two different regex for the following string:

`eturk/clock, eturk/vermonster, and noted/noted#42`

One of the regex should recognize just the repo (without the issue). So for the first regex, it should just return these matches:

`[["eturk", "clock"], ["eturk", "vermonster"]]`

And then for the second one, it should recognize the issue along with the repo. So the match would be:

`[["noted", "noted", "42"]]`

---

This is what I have so far for the first part:

```
/(\w*)\/(\w*)?/
```

This would match like this:

`[["eturk", "clock"], ["eturk", "vermonster"], ["noted", "noted"]]`

But the thing is, I don't want it to match the reference to the repo with the issue attached. Can anyone offer any help on this?

Comment: I think you have a typo...right after "it should just return these matches", don't you mean to say `[["eturk", "clock"], ["eturk","vermonster"]]`?

Comment: Alex has your answer, but in other contexts this may be helpful: `"noted/noted#42".split /[\/#]/ # => ["noted", "noted", "42"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Regex #1

```
/\b(\w+)\/(\w+(?!#\d+))\b/
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/VrdzOui0ks)

---

---

#### Regex #2

```
/\b(\w+)\/(\w+)#(\d+)\b/
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/rLzKJmcize)

Comment: Good answer, Alex!  It's what I was going to suggest, and you have a pretty picture to boot.

Comment: Two pretty pictures, now three.

Comment: In #2 regex and image is not the same. In the regex # is part of the group, however on the image it isn't.

Comment: This works, but what Gergo said is correct. This is it fixed: `/\b(\w+)\/(\w+)#(\d+)\b/`

Comment: Out of curiousity, what did you use to generate the images?